# validation not working for js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal cmxform" id="validateForm" method="get" action="../../course_controller" autocomplete="off">


<input type="text" id="course_name" name="course_name" placeholder="Enter Course Name..." class="row-fluid" required onkeyup="javaScript:validate_course_name();">
<label id="course_name_info" style="color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);font-size:13px">
</label>



<button type="submit" name="user_action" value="add" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="javaScript:validate();" >Save</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>



</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
/**** Specific JS for this page ****/

//Validation things




function validate_course_name(){

var TCode = document.getElementById('course_name').value;

if( /[^a-zA-Z1-9 _-]/.test( TCode ) ) {

course_name_info.innerHTML="Please Enter Only Alphanumeric or _,-,' ' ";
return false;
}
else
{
course_name_info.innerHTML=" ";
return true;
}


}
function validate(){


validate_course_name();

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So this the code ...I am applying alpha numeric validation on one field but even if i give invalid input like some other characters the form is getting submitted where am i doing it wrong?
i am very new to this web so any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: As @Duffmaster33 said simply change onClick to javascript:return validate_course_name();

Comment: Is that carrot suppose to left anchor? I think it goes out of the character set brackets. Also if you left anchor, why not right anchor? And character sets only match a single char, you'd want + for at least one. `/^[a-z whatever]+$/` maybe?

Comment: @fattomkh its not working

Comment: @darkporter nopes it right the way i did it ...problem is some where else:S

Comment: Oh right, the carrot negates the character set, not anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here.  First, you are never returning the result, so even if the function results in false, it is not returned to the form so the form goes on its merry way.  To fix, you can add an onsubmit to the form tag, or even better attach an onsubmit event to the form.

```
onsubmit="return validate();"
```

Second, you only need the one function, calling a function from another function is not necessary here, and results in an additional level of difficulty since you will need to return the result to the wrapper function, which will then need to return that result to the form.

```
//Validation things
function validate() {
    var TCode = document.getElementById('course_name').value;
    if (/[^a-zA-Z1-9 _-]/.test(TCode)) {
        course_name_info.innerHTML = "Please Enter Only Alphanumeric or _,-,' ' ";
        return false;
    } else {
        course_name_info.innerHTML = " ";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is a working fiddle of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/duffmaster33/nCKhH/

Comment: i need to call more than one function in that validate function...i just did that to make it simple

Answer (score 1):

Your validate() function should return the result of the validation. Currently the result of validate_course_name is discarded. In other words, it should look something like this

```
function validate(){
    return validate_course_name();
}
```

Also you might want to move the validation to

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()" ...
```

Comment: well the validation function is calling validate_course_name() which is returning the result

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I added some example code to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap course_name_info with a getElementById

```
document.getElementById('course_name_info').innerHTML="Please Enter Only Alphanumeric or _,-,' ' ";
```

and then change the style of the label so the font isn't white on white background.

Hope that fixes it.

Comment: Try it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gTvvuPtKFDa4jTaZ6y0m It appears you are accepting any letter, number, _, or - so I used the * and received your error message.